# Django - Unable to access css file in static under root folder. Error 404 in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, python-3.x, web

I am unable to access 'css' and 'js' files placed in 'static' folder under the root folder. The following error is displayed in the log - [11/May/2018 11:07:33] "GET /static/home.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1648

below is settings.py

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/
 DEBUG = True
 INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 ]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
 STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
 ]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
```

Part my the html template:

```
<head>
    <title>HomePage</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href={% static '/home.css' %}>
    <script type="text/javascript" src={% static '/home.js'%}></script>
</head>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
.
.
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

When I try to access css manually by typing 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/home.css' in the browser I get

```
Page not found (404)
 Request Method:    GET
 Request URL:   http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/home.css
 Raised by: django.views.static.serve
 'home.css' could not be found
```

Also, I was thinking how I could have same css throughout my application?
Aand, what if I add the css and js in my html template directly? Will it be a problem when I deploy in production?

Comment: Have you set `STATIC_ROOT`? because I can't see that defined in your settings

Comment: No, I just added but still the same error.STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')

Answer (score 0):

If the ressource is not here you need to collectstatic:

The ressource need to be in `app/static`

`python manage.py collectstatic`

and dont use `{% static '/home.css' %}` but `{% static 'home.css' %}`

Comment: It css works after add the below lines to settings.py and remove '/'    
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = ( os.path.join('static'), )